# Booting Refind from UEFI GRUB2

Tags: uefi, grub2, refind

I'm trying to boot Refind from the UEFI GRUB2, with the following commands, but I'm getting an error:

`grub> chainloader (hd0)/refind_x64.efi
/EndEntire
file path: /ACPI(..../File(refind_x64.efi)/EndEntire
grub> boot
error: unknown error.`

In fact, I get the same error when I try to boot the EFI shell version 2.

Somebody else got the same error message: https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/UEFI/

The filesystem containing `refind_x64.efi` is ext2 directly on the device, there are no partitions.

How can I boot Refind from UEFI GRUB2?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I ran into the same problem while trying to boot Windows 10. Maybe `set root=(hd0,Y); ($root)refind_x64.efi` would work? (Can't test it right now.)